# Discord.py | Add roles

Tags: discord.py

I'm new to creating bots on discord and can't figure out how I can add a role to multiple users simply by writing a chat message.
I have tried to search various methods on the internet but all I add the role to the author of the message while I need it to add the role to specific users

Comment: Can you show some code, what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a command using [discord.ext.commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/).

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@bot.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def add_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *users: discord.Member):
    for user in users:
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

You should call it as follows `{prefix}add_role @role @user1 @user2`

Your setup should look like this

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

#code here

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Hi, I try to use your code but unfortunately it doesn't work. Can you help me again? I think that the problem is the for cycle becouse if I add a print before that, the console print the word and i had to change command.command in client.command

Comment: Hi, I tried again but now it gives me a problem in the code saying that: "Instance of 'Bot' has no 'has_permissions' memberpylint (no-member)", while if I try to change from bot.has_permissions to commands.has_permissions it doesn't give me more errors and seems to hang to await

Comment: You should leave it as the format i gave. Make sure it has a permission in the guild to `manage roles` give it a role with that permission.